# How to get HTML code from URL in Chrome Browser using java?

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, yahoo

When I open Yahoo movies web site, say The dark knight(http://movies.yahoo.com/movie/the-dark-knight/), the web site is viewed differently according to Broswer(in my case, Chrome vs Explorer). So the HTML code are different from each other. 
In order to get HTML source code by Chrome, I coded in java as follows:

```
StringBuilder parsedContentFromUrl = new StringBuilder();
HttpURLConnection uc;
uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36 CoolNovo/2.0.9.20");
uc.setRequestMethod("GET");
uc.connect();
uc.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
int ch;
while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    parsedContentFromUrl.append((char) ch);
}
String content = parsedContentFromUrl.toString();
```

Although I want to get HTML code from CHROME, but the output is from EXPLORER. Please let me know how I can get Chrome version HTML using JAVA.

Comment: Have you checked the codes manually and saw that the **HTML** is different?

Answer (score 2):

What you have written so far will return the *initial* data stream. To duplicate the behavior in a browser you need something implementing all the functionality (html parsing, DOM building, javascript execution, css rendering, fetching linked data, etc) of a browser to handle the dynamically generated DOM content.  Reading data from a `HttpURLConnection` is just the first of many required steps. By the time you're done you will have duplicated a modern browser.  That's a huge amount of work.